# Local variable get changed unintentionally in Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, variables

I have a pandas dataframe "df" on which I apply several functions. 
I do not want to change the values of the original dataframe.
All my functions look like this:

```
def func(x):
# do some stuff with x
return x

 y = func(x=df)
```

I do not refer to the df variable within the function. But the variable get changed anyway. Can someone explain to me why that's the case and how to avoid it?

Comment: Python is pass-by-reference. `df` is mutable. You're passing a reference to `df` to the method which is mutating it. If you want to keep the original intact, send in a copy of `df`

Comment: @rdas It is not the case that Python is pass-by-reference. Python uses an evaluation strategy called [call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). This is not a well-known name, and it is sometimes called "call by assignment", or if in Java community, "call by value where all values are references".  Whatever you want to call it, it is *not* call-by-reference. The distinguishing feature of call by reference here would be that *assignments to a parameter would be seen by the caller*, which doesn't happen in Python

Answer (score 1):

Send a deepcopy of the dataframe

```
y = func(x=df.copy())
```

Which by default is a deepcopy.

Comment: This will pass in a shallow copy, which may be enough :)

Comment: @Mars not according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) it will. It says `deep default is True`

Comment: Good catch! I forgot that it was a pandas dataframe. Python's copy() is shallow by default. Whoops!